# How to use 선물할 거다 in the grammar -게 아니라

Tags: grammar

This is the excercise
[image]

Should I write
“선물할 게 아니라 선물 받았어요.”

Or what is the correct form of the sentence?

Thanks

Comment: '선물할 게 아니라 선물 받은 거에요' is more natural.

Comment: Thank you so much!